# Remove Text before Word in Javascript / jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

'Remove stuff before this **word**. Hello!'

How can I remove the text before 'word' in the above string in javascript or jQuery?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use "substring" combined with "indexOf":

```
var sample = 'Remove stuff before this word. Hello!';
var substr = sample.substring(sample.indexOf('word')); //substr = 'word. Hello!'
```

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative:

```
var str = "Remove stuff before this word. Hello!"  
str = str.replace(/.*(?=word)/i, "");
```