# Jquery remove words from text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have string, for example:

$string = 'Text lorem ipsum text-1 text-2'.

How can i delete, using jquery or javascript, all words that contains 'text'. So after delete it will be only 'lorem ipsum' ? Thanks for help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove Text before Word in Javascript / jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275724/remove-text-before-word-in-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression for this. I assume the criteria is to select `text` and then any character until a space character is found.

```js
var string = 'Text lorem ipsum text-1 text-2';

var result = string.replace(/text\S*/gi, "");

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends, I find the easiest way, if you have no idea what else is going to be in the string:

`var string = 'Text lorem ipsum text-1 text-2';`

`var parsedString = string.match('lorem ipsum')[0];`

`console.log(parsedString)`

The benefit here is you don't need to know what else may be in the string.

Comment: That is exacly what what i'm looking for. Big thanks !

Comment: @Pat: If that's what you want, then you don't need any special functions. Just do `var result = "lorem ipsum"`

Comment: @CrazyTrain sometimes I don't even ask myself why someone would be asking such a thing, but this is the best example of that I have seen here. I really have no idea what the use case for the code I just posted would be lol, I mean you have to pass a string into it so of course you already know the string....

Comment: lol, yep. If the OP is happy with it, then I guess that's all that matters. :)